# Django to desktop app with pyinstaller

Tags: django, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert a django project into a desktop app.
I've downloaded the developer version of pyinstaller: github/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.

hookutils.py is modified as stated here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/754 in order for pyinstaller to find my root directory: *Django root directory c:\Workspace\mysite\mysite*

The project I'm trying to compile is the initial project gotten after running: *django-admin.py startproject mysite*, so no apps created yet.

When following the steps as described on pyinstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication) I get some errors when trying to run the server (
.\dist\mysite\mysite.exe runserver localhost:8080):

```
c:\Workspace\compiled>.\dist\mysite\mysite.exe runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management", line 392, in execute
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management", line 263, in fetch_command
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management", line 109, in get_commands
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.conf", line 53, in __getattr__
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.conf", line 49, in _setup
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.conf", line 71, in _configure_logging
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.utils.log", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.views.debug", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.http", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.http.cookie", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.utils.six", line 84, in __get__
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.utils.six", line 103, in _resolve
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.utils.six", line 74, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named Cookie
```

If I then import Cookie in manage.py then, another error appears:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x02D86CF0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management.commands.runserver", line 92, in inner_run
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management.base", line 280, in validate
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.core.management.validation", line 35, in get_validation_errors
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.db.models.loading", line 166, in get_app_errors
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.db.models.loading", line 75, in _populate
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.db.models.loading", line 96, in load_app
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.utils.importlib", line 35, in import_module
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.contrib.auth.models", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.contrib.auth.hashers", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.test", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Workspace\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\Workspace\compiled\build\mysite\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.test.testcases", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _doctest
```

I have tried to import doctest, but it doesn't help.

Using python 2.7.4 and django 1.5.1

**Edit:**
So by adding django.test and HTMLParser to the manage.py, I got it to work:

```
import os
import sys
import Cookie

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "OTA.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    import django.test
    import HTMLParser
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django imports local doctest module. Maybe try `import django.test`?

Also from the PyInstaller docs about including additional modules:

> - You can give additional files on the PyInstaller command line.
> - You can give additional import paths on the command line.
> - You can edit the myscript.spec file that PyInstaller writes the first time you run
>     it for your script. In the spec file you can tell PyInstaller about code and data files that are unique to your script.
> - You can write "hook" files that inform PyInstaller of hidden imports. If you "hook" imports for a package that other users might also use, you can contribute your hook file to PyInstaller.

I also recommend py2exe, if PyInstaller won't meet Your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. After importing django.test HTMLParser also pop'ed up as an error, but importing that, and everything is running.

Comment: When trying to run my actual project (with views and database) I get the error: 
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing email backend module django.core.mail.backends.smtp: "No module named smtp"

Comment: If You want to send e-mails, then You need to include the missing modules in Your build (maybe just `import django.core.mail.backends` in `manage.py`?). If You don't want to send e-mail, then set `EMAIL_BACKEND` in your settings to `'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'`.

Comment: Thank you once again. Maybe also you can also help with the next one:
`AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Comment: Don't have idea, seems like a bug in Your code, but can't tell without more info.

Comment: Okay. Thank you anyway. The project works fine until compiling it with pyinstaller and trying to run the .exe server . 
But will try leaving some parts of the code out and see when it starts working :)