# Django project to .exe with Pyinstaller - Missing modules, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, executable, pyinstaller

I am working to convert my Django project to a .exe file using Pyinstaller. I want to be able to just click an icon and open the project in a browser. Here is my folder structure:

```
proj
    __pycache__
    proj
        __pycache__
        __init__.py
        manage.py
        Dashboard
            __pycache__
            __init__.py
            urls.py
        proj
            __pycache__
            __init__.py
            settings.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
    static_cdn
```

And here is my manage.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
    print("here")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    import django.test
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Currently I cd to C:...\proj, then run `pyinstaller --name=Dashboard proj/manage.py`. Then when I click on Dashboard.exe in C:...\proj\dist\Dashboard, an error comes up.[image: errorMessage]

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. I think I may either have something wrong with my folder structure, or I may be calling the pyinstaller in the wrong folder. Any help is super appreciated!

Additional information:

- I am following directions from [this tutorial](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django) on how to make a .exe
- A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001009/django-import-error-no-module-named-apps/30001066?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) suggested adding an `__init__.py` file to C:...\proj\proj, however this makes the pyinstaller function fail with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.settings'`.
- I followed the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494620/django-to-desktop-app-with-pyinstaller?rq=1) in my manage.py file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the folder structure is fine, it was missing an import. In my `manage.py` file, I added the line "`import Dashboard`".

However, after I tried to run  pyinstaller again it said it was missing more modules, like `django.contrib.admin.apps`. The missing modules seem to be coming from my settings.py file. [image]

To import these, I added them to my SPEC file. Whenever I had run pyinstaller before, it had added three new items: a build folder, a dist folder, and a Dashboard.spec file. In the SPEC file I appended my installed app names from settings (plus .apps) to the hiddenimports list.

Here is the entirety of my .spec file.
[image]

This solved the problem and it compiled fine.

EDIT:

I eventually added more hiddenImports than listed above. Here are all the hiddenImports that I currently use.

```
hiddenimports=['django.contrib.admin.apps', 'django.contrib.auth.apps', 'django.contrib.contenttypes.apps', 'django.contrib.sessions.apps', 'django.contrib.messages.apps', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.apps', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers', 'django.template.loaders', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors']
```

Comment: I had the same issue as you with apps that I added to my settings.py.  Your solution to editing the spec file helped me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the additional files you had to add to hiddenimport?

Comment: Based on your edit i'm assuming we are having the same issue with the django.contrib.messages.middleware, etc. not coming over correctly.  Even though the hook was included it's still occuring.

Comment: running pyinstaller again basically overwrites the .spec, how can I rerun pyinstaller without overwriting the .spec

Comment: @PolarBear10, if you run `pyinstaller name.spec` it will use the settings in the .spec file. If you don't want to use the .spec file and do not want to overwrite it, I guess just rename it.

Comment: what if I have more external pip packages or libraries. do i do that as hidden imports as well and how with path?

Comment: @Gary, if they are available on Pip you can add them to `hiddenimports`. If they are not, you could add them to `datas`. You can find more info in Pyinstaller's documentation.